# Создание каталога средствами php

Tags: php

```
$id_galery = strtotime("now");
$uploaddir = PATH_ROOT.'img/gal/small/'.$id_galery;
$uploaddir2 = PATH_ROOT.'img/gal/big/'.$id_galery;
mkdir($uploaddir,0777);
mkdir($uploaddir2,0777);
```

На винде работает, на линуксе нет, в чем проблема?

Не знаю, какой Макар так решил, но если сделать так:

```
$uploaddir = PATH_ROOT."img/gal/small/$id_galery";
 $uploaddir2 = PATH_ROOT."img/gal/big/$id_galery";
```

Comment: А какое конечное значение переменных $uploаddir?  Может, где-то слэш съедается?

Comment: если бы что то где то съедалось, на винде бы не работало

Comment: @LLIAKAJI отличный аргумент!

Comment: Серьёзно? А то, что в винде нормально работает и path/to/file, и /path/to/file, и даже варианты /path/to/file/, path/to/file/? А в линуксе всё не так гладко.

Кстати да, вы хоть пользователю, который эти папки создаёт, разрешили их создавать в том месте, где он это делает?

Comment: все уже гладше, чем покрытие на капоте спортивной тачки, и если ЧО, в моем коде используется  /path/to/file для обоих случаев, так что, товариЩ знаток, нужно лучше смотреть или не позориться

Answer (score 1):

```
PATH_ROOT.'img/gal/small/'
PATH_ROOT.'img/gal/big/'
```

Проверьте права доступа. Должны быть 0777. Разрешения для винды и никсов по-разному работают.